# PHP syntax help on if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to determine the right syntax from what I'm trying to do with MySQL. I'm basically saying that if a value in a certain column of a row of a table is equal to some session variables, I want to echo out info.

I have a table with `subject`, `description` and `user`. `User` is set by taking the current user's first name and last name and inserting it into the table under `user`. This is done by the following code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_name (subject, description, user)
VALUES
('$_POST[subject]','$_POST[description]','$_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]')";
```

Then once I'm calling this data back out, I want to basically allow the user to delete content that they submitted themselves. The first step for me is to be able to display it in the table. I believe this is just syntax error, but I've confused myself now with how things are set up:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY subject, description 
  LIMIT {$startpoint},{$limit}";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows>0){
$field_num = $mysqli->field_count;
echo "<h1>HERE ARE SOME EXAMPLES:</h1>";
echo "<table border='0'><tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td>{$field->subject}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$field->description}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$field->user}</td>";
        if('$field->user' == '$_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]'){
          echo '<td>You can delete this</td>';
        }
    }
```

I figured the `$field->user` would equal `$_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]` because that's how it was initially submitted to the table (without the '.' for concatenation).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

### EDIT

Here's the result of my table output code. The results are actually being display with $cell instead of from within the for loop I believe. I've added the if statement in after the but it doesn't seem to recognize `echo "<td>".$field->user."</td>";` which makes me think that that is where the problem lies. What I would like to do is be able to add the if statement in a  immediately after `echo {$field->user}"; to keep the code clean. I think I've confused myself thoroughly:

```
if($num_rows>0){
$field_num = $mysqli->field_count;
echo "<h1>HERE ARE SOME JOBS:</h1>";
echo "<table border='0'><tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->subject}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$field->description}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$field->user}</td>";

    if($field->user == $_SESSION[firstname]." ".$_SESSION[lastname]){
    echo '<td>You can delete this</td>';
    }
    else{
    echo "<td>".$field->user."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$_SESSION[firstname]." ".$_SESSION[lastname]."</td>";
    }
}

echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo"<tr>";

    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else{
echo 'There are no jobs!';
}
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes surrounding the variables in the if condition

Comment: That still didn't display the "You can delete this" text. It actually gave an error until I concatenated it with a '.' Then I tried to add $_SESSION[firstname]." ".$_SESSION[lastname] in hopes that it was reading it right but it still didn't provide the solution. I'm currently logged in as a user and submitted a post so it should be matched up.

Comment: Add an else condition and echo both `$field->user` and `$_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname']`, and see if they are matching.

Comment: Good call, I'll try that now.

Comment: I added edits above. I believe the problem lies in calling $field->user right now. I can echo out the session variable but not the $field->user variable. I've added edits above.

Comment: You seem to be using `mysqli` functions and `mysql_fetch_field`. Use only one type.

Comment: If you want to print the column names, use `$field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";`. But you cannot get value in `user` column here.

Comment: I ended up using mysqli_fetch_array instead. It may not have been the most elegant way to do it but it worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: var_dump($field); in your for-loop would display the data structure of $field. This is one of the most handy functions in PHP. It can be a bit hard to read in the browser, but look at the page source in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote the code in a way that was a little bit easier for me to understand (though maybe not the shortest way to do it):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$row['subject']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['user']."</td>";
    if($row['user'] == $_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname']){
    echo"<td>You can delete this</td>";
    }
    else{
    echo"<td>Code didn't work</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

It ended up working this way. If there's way to do this shorter then feel free to post it here otherwise thanks for the help!